# How to run ESLint on all files (even closed ones) in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, eslint

In Visual Studio 2019, I have set the following option:

> Tools -> Text Editor -> Javascript/Typescript -> Linting -> Lint all files included in project, even closed files = Checked

That setting shows a disclaimer:

> This setting is ignored when diagnostics are only reported for open files

I assume that is why VS isn't linting all files (unless I open them first).

How do I turn on diagnostic reporting for closed files so that ESlint reports on every file in the project?

Comment: In case you want eslint to run and fix all problems in all files you can do `npx eslint --fix src`, substitute src for the folder you want to apply eslint. Got reference from [this github issue.](https://github.com/MiguelCastillo/Brackets-InteractiveLinter/issues/183)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the setting that turns off diagnostics are only reported for open files;

> Tools -> Text Editor -> Javascript/Typescript -> Project -> General -> Only report diagnostics for opened files in the editor - UNCHECK

This worked for me to get ESLint Error and Warnings on ALL files - open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but in VS Code 2022 on Mac I can't find a way to enable/disable this option:

> Tools -> Text Editor -> Javascript/Typescript -> Project -> General ->
> Only report diagnostics for opened files in the editor - UNCHECK

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a new question, rather than an answer. You'll get more help if you post it as an actual question, perhaps linked to this one.